# Android: How To Detect When Activity Inside a Thread is Finished

Tags: android

I'm starting an activity inside a thread like this:

```
Thread newPage = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(getBaseContext(), Page.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        getBaseContext().startActivity(i);
    }
};
newPage.start();
```

and I want to call a function when the activity finishes - how can i do that?

Comment: @DigCamara startActivity is not waiting 'til Activity finish ...

Comment: in onPause() check if(isFinishing()) i think

Comment: @Selvin you're absolutely right. Easiest way: change the whole code to use startActivityForResult (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way: change your whole approach to [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

**Page** class overwrite [finish](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) method.

```
public void finish() {
   //DO something you like
   super.finish();
}
```